How to share a boolean flag with a scoped thread in Rust?
I am trying to use a boolean flag to signal that a thread should exit. However, currently my code violates the borrow checker rules. I understand why it violates these rules, however what I do not know is what the most appropriate design is and how that may fix the problem.
fn long_running(exit_flag: &bool) {

    loop {
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10));

        if *exit_flag {
            break;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut exit_flag = false;
    std::thread::scope(
        |scope| {
            let handle = scope.spawn(
                || {
                    long_running(&exit_flag); # (1)
                }
            );

            exit_flag = true; # (2)

            // terminate the consumer poll loop
            handle.join().expect("failed to join thread");
        }
    );
}

The problem involves the lines marked with # (1) and # (2).

# (1): Reference to exit_flag is borrowed
# (2): Attempting to mutate underlying variable while reference is still borrowed

This is not permitted because of the borrow checker rules.

One solution to the problem might be to heap allocate the flag, and use this to share the data between the two threads.
However, the intention of using std::thread::scope was to permit launching a thread which has access to a local variable from the stack of the parent (main) thread.

btw got the idea of doing this from this thread

How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?


You need an AtomicBool. And I believe your understanding of C++ is incorrect.

@kmdreko Can you show an example of using AtomicBool? I managed to get this to work inside of an Arc, but perhaps the Arc is not necessary? Also happy to discuss your thoughts on C++ in the comments. You can perhaps explain a bit more detail.

Using Arc is not necessary here: All that Arc does is give you the ability to extend the lifetime of whatever is in Arc out to 'static, which is a requirement of a free-standing thread, but not of a scoped thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/9200951/2189130

@kmdreko That's interesting - I think in this case it is ok on the basis that it will be eventually consistent - meaning that the change to the boolean value will be eventually picked up by the other thread, even in the presence of this caching issue. But tbh I can see that it isn't very good design. I'll remove that comment from the post.

The C++ standard calls it a data race. The compiler may see your value is not written in the current thread and not synchronized and thus conclude it never changes and optimize it out. So platform architecture wouldn't be a factor in that case. It is not "ok", use proper synchronization - in both C++ and Rust.

This does not work because exit_flag is to be borrowed by the thread's closure while also being mutated via exit_flag = true;. In other words, there is no guarantee that the thread has stopped observing exit_flag while it is being mutated (which in fact is the whole point of exit_flag).
You'll need an AtomicBool to do that:
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

fn long_running(exit_flag: &AtomicBool) {
    loop {
        println!("Working...");
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(3));
        if exit_flag.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let exit_flag = AtomicBool::new(false);
    std::thread::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| {
            long_running(&exit_flag);
        });
        exit_flag.store(true, Ordering::Relaxed);
    });
    println!("Done");
}

Notice that I removed handle.join(), as thread::scope already guarantees that all threads have been joined when it returns.

This is really excellent - I suspected there was no need for Arc but I don't know why my code would not compile the first time around

Note that depending on what you want to do, an ordering stricter than Relaxed may be necessary to avoid race conditions (but not data races).

You might also want to look at CondVar so you can merge the sleep with the check, and stop sleeping immediately as the condvar gets set.

@user2138149, if this answers your question, please mark it as answered - both for keeping the queue clean, and for general profit and glory
